# Completing a beginner script in python

Tags: python, list

Hello Im trying to complete an exercise in a no starch book. I am stuck on exercise 8-11. I am trying to return a list in a function and then print out the list in that function, but I am having some trouble. I will post the question and my code. Thank y'all for your assistance.

8-9. Magicians:
 Make a list of magician’s names
 . Pass the list to a function 
called 
show_magicians()
, which prints the name of each magician in the list
 .

8-10. Great Magicians:
 Start with a copy of your program from Exercise 8-9
 . 
Write a function called make_great() that modifies the list of magicians by adding the phrase 
the Great
 to each magician’s name
 . Call 
show_magicians()
 to 
see that the list has actually been modified
 .

8-11. Unchanged Magicians:
 Start with your work from Exercise 8-10
 . Call the 
function 
make_great()
 with a copy of the list of magicians’ names
 . Because the 
original list will be unchanged, return the new list and store it in a separate list
 . 
Call 
show_magicians()
 with each list to show that you have one list of the origi
nal names and one list with 
the Great
 added to each magician’s name

```
magicians = ['chris', 'niko', 'luke']
new_list =[]
def show_magicians(magicians):
    for i in magicians:
        new = "Great " + i.title()
    return new_list.append(new)

print(show_magicians(magicians[:]))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 1):

So when defining a function, if you have input, you symbolize that input with a local variable of sorts, like this:

```
list_of_stuff = ['stuff', 'goes', 'here', 'hi']
def print_stuff(local_variable_thats_name_is_not_used_elsewhere):
    for i in local_variable_thats_name_is_not_used_elsewhere:
        print i
```

Then call the list when you call the function.